# Is NHibernate supported on SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2005-express

I want to use SQL Server 2005 Express as database. Will NHibernate be supported with it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is supported.

A tutorial ( https://web.archive.org/web/20130926011158/http://www.svendtofte.com/serverside/setting-up-nhibernate-20/ ) goes over setting up NHibernate and uses SQL Express 2005

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use:

- **Driver** - `NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver`
- **Dialect** - `NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect`

Comment: For a shorter configuration, you can avoid specifying the driver since the dialect will indicate its preferred driver.